# Which .NET class parses a multiple HTTP cookies string into a CookieCollection or CookieContainer?

Tags: .net, http, cookies

I am sure it already exists somewhere, just can't find it.

Comment: For reference, the actual parsing class is called CookieParser (accurate), but is internal.. its functionality is exposed via the container.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it sounds like you want the `CookieContainer.SetCookies` method:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer.setcookies.aspx

Followed by the `CookieContainer.GetCookies` method to get the parsed `CookieCollection`:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer.getcookies.aspx