# How to read cookies from HttpResponseMessage?

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

This is my recent code:

```
HttpClient authClient = new HttpClient();
authClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:4999/test_db/_session");
authClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var user = new LoginUserSecretModel
{
    name = userKey,
    password = loginData.Password,
};
HttpResponseMessage authenticationResponse = authClient.PostAsJsonAsync("", user).Result;
```

Comment: Anyway, don't use `Result`. Use `await authClient.PostAsJsonAsync()` instead.

Answer (score 33):

The issue I have with many of the answers here is that using `CookieContainer` uses [short-lived `HttpClient` objects which is not recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Instead, you can simply read the `"Set-Cookie"` header from the response:

```cs
// httpClient is long-lived and comes from a IHttpClientFactory
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
IEnumerable<string> cookies = response.Headers.SingleOrDefault(header => header.Key == "Set-Cookie").Value;
```

If the `"Set-Cookie"` header is not present, `cookies` will be null.

Comment: Once we get the "cookies" string, is there a clean way to obtain a specific cookie value? It feels a bit clunky to have to parse the string to extract the actual cookie value. I assume there's probably be a helper method in .Net to handle it, but most of my researches circle back to CookieContainer which we can't use when reusing our HttpClient instance.

Comment: Best answer if a person wants to have both a response and the cookies from that response. In my humble opinion, parsing the string is trivial.

Comment: KeyValuePair is not nullable

Comment: Small technicality: `KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>` cannot be tested for null so `?.Value` is a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks @cubesnyc and @Hari, I've fixed the answer and added a line describing what happens if there is no `"Set-Cookie"` header.

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.CookieContainer = cookies;

HttpClient authClient = new HttpClient(handler);

var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:4999/test_db/_session");

authClient.BaseAddress = uri;
authClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var user = new LoginUserSecretModel
{
    name = userKey,
    password = loginData.Password,
};

HttpResponseMessage authenticationResponse = authClient.PostAsJsonAsync("", user).Result;

var responseCookies = cookies.GetCookies(uri).Cast<Cookie>();
```

Comment: thank you for your answer .... but "cookie" count was 0 and nothing containing when i get HttpResponseMassage.

Comment: Are you sure cookies are being set?

Comment: yes i already set,  i found the cookies are in authenticationResponse.headers.

Comment: Are the cookies secure? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681144/httpclient-not-storing-cookies-in-cookiecontainer

Comment: `cookies` is a different object to `authenticationResponse`. The `cookies` object is just an empty object. `CookieContainer` is just a data structure for cookies to be put into... this answer does not put anything into it from the `authenticationResponse` object.

Comment: Also, if you are using HttpClient as a shared instance for many parallel requests (as it is recommended https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/ ) , be aware that cookies in the handler might belong to a different parallel response, not the one you just received. Unless you do some locking for every request to avoid such cookie race conditions.

Answer (score 6):

This is what you need to get a list of cookies;

```
    private async Task<List<Cookie>> GetCookies(string url, string cookieName)
    {
        var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        var uri = new Uri(url);
        using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            CookieContainer = cookieContainer
        })
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
            {
                await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
                List<Cookie> cookies = cookieContainer.GetCookies(uri).Cast<Cookie>().ToList();
                return cookies;
            }
        }
    }
```

and if you need only one cookie value here's how

```
 private async Task<string> GetCookieValue(string url)
        {
            var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            var uri = new Uri(url);
            using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                CookieContainer = cookieContainer
            })
            {
                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
                {
                    await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
                    var cookie = cookieContainer.GetCookies(uri).Cast<Cookie>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == cookieName);
                    return cookie?.Value;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

Building on top of [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60345759/592732) and [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1249441/592732), this would be an easy way to read the cookies from an HTTP response.

```
// httpClient is long-lived and comes from a IHttpClientFactory
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
foreach (var cookieHeader in response.Headers.GetValues("Set-Cookie"))
    cookies.SetCookies(uri, cookieHeader);
string cookieValue = cookies.GetCookies(uri).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "MyCookie")?.Value;
```

Comment: This worked better for me because I have a shared HttpClient instance and didn't need to work with cookies on all of the endpoints.