# Reverse proxy in .NET Core Middleware “set-cookie” response does not set in browser and not showing in HttpResponseMessage

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, session-cookies, cookiecontainer, asp.net-session

Here I am making a reverse proxy server to bypass an ASP.NET web application (following [this tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/building-a-reverse-proxy-in-dot-net-core/)). I am trying to read the session ID cookie from `HttpResponseMessage`. I used a cookie container as well but am unable to find it. Implemented in ASP.NET core invoke method, session is working properly but unable to catch session ID in request or response.

```
            public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IBrowserDetector detector)
            {
                //context.Session.SetString(SessionKeyName, "The Doctor");
                var browser = detector.Browser;
                var targetUri = BuildTargetUri(context.Request);
                if (context.Request.Method != HttpMethod.Get.Method)
                {
                    var remoteIp = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
                    //var gg= context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey.;
                    var clienttdatetime = context.Request.Headers["Date"].ToString();
                    //_logger.LogDebug("Request from Remote IP address: {RemoteIp}", remoteIp);
                    var badIp = true;
                    var bytes = remoteIp.GetAddressBytes();
                    //var testIp = IPAddress.Parse(address);
                    //if (testIp.GetAddressBytes().SequenceEqual(bytes))
                    //{
                    //    badIp = false;
                    //    break;
                    //}
                    if (remoteIp.IsIPv4MappedToIPv6)
                    {
                        remoteIp = remoteIp.MapToIPv4();
                    }
                    IPAddress remoteIpAddress = context.Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
                    string result = "";
                    if (remoteIpAddress != null)
                    {
                        // If we got an IPV6 address, then we need to ask the network for the IPV4 address 
                        // This usually only happens when the browser is on the same machine as the server.
                        if (remoteIpAddress.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
                        {
                            remoteIpAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(remoteIpAddress).AddressList
                    .First(x => x.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
                        }
                        result = remoteIpAddress.ToString();
                    }
                    if (badIp)
                    {
                        //_logger.LogWarning(
                        //    "Forbidden Request from Remote IP address: {RemoteIp}", remoteIp);
                        //context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden;
                        //return;
                    }
                }
    
    
                if (targetUri != null)
                {
                    CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
                    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
                    handler.CookieContainer = cookies;
                    var targetRequestMessage = CreateTargetMessage(context, targetUri);
    
                    using (var responseMessage = await _httpClient.SendAsync(targetRequestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.RequestAborted))
                    {
                        IEnumerable<Cookie> responseCookies = cookies.GetCookies(targetUri).Cast<Cookie>();
                        foreach (Cookie cookie_ in responseCookies)
                           Console.WriteLine(cookie_.Name + ": " + cookie_.Value);
                        // ExtractCookiesFromResponse(responseMessage);
                        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)responseMessage.StatusCode;
                        CopyFromTargetResponseHeaders(context, responseMessage);
                        await responseMessage.Content.CopyToAsync(context.Response.Body);
                        //if(responseMessage.RequestMessage.RequestUri.ToString()== "http://localhost:51125/Menu.aspx")
                        //{
                        //Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:5000/login.aspx");
                        //Build the request
                       //Uri site = targetUri;
                       // HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(site);
                       // CookieContainer cookiesq = new CookieContainer();
                       // request.CookieContainer = cookiesq;
    
                       // //Print out the number of cookies before the response (of course it will be blank)
                       // Console.WriteLine(cookiesq.GetCookieHeader(site),"1");
    
                       // //Get the response and print out the cookies again
                       // using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                       // {
                       //     Console.WriteLine(cookiesq.GetCookieHeader(site), "2");
                       // }
    
                       // Console.ReadKey();
    
    
                        //}
                        var cookie = context.Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"];
                    }
                    return;
                }
                await _nextMiddleware(context);
            }

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      public static IDictionary<string, string> ExtractCookiesFromResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
        {
            IDictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            IEnumerable<string> values;
            if (response.Headers.TryGetValues("Set-Cookie", out values))
            {
                SetCookieHeaderValue.ParseList(values.ToList()).ToList().ForEach(cookie =>
                {
                    result.Add(cookie.Name.ToString(), cookie.Value.ToString());
                });
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
               CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
               HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
               handler.CookieContainer = cookies;
               _httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
                var targetRequestMessage = CreateTargetMessage(context, targetUri);

                using (var responseMessage = await _httpClient.SendAsync(targetRequestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.RequestAborted))
                {
                    //var responseCookies = cookies.GetCookies(targetUri).Cast<Cookie>();
                    IEnumerable<Cookie> responseCookies = cookies.GetCookies(targetUri).Cast<Cookie>();
                    foreach (Cookie cookie in responseCookies)
                    {
                        if(cookie.Name=="ASP.NET_SessionId")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(cookie.Name + ": " + cookie.Value);
                            context.Response.Headers.Add("Set-Cookie", cookie.Name+"="+cookie.Value);
                        }
                        
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you created the `HttpClientHandler` but didn't use it to build the `HttpClient` to make your request. You are still using the static `_httpClient` that nothing knows about the cookie container you created.
This should be the reason why you get the `CookieContainer` still empty.

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29224734/how-to-read-cookies-from-httpresponsemessage) to learn how to get cookies from an `HttpResponseMessage`.

Comment: Happy to hear this! :-)